# Java веб стэк технологий

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring

Вроде изучаю Spring, но тем не менее никак не могу понять(и найти), реальный пример с продакшн стэком технологий, которые используют в реальных проектах.

Например я знаю так: Spring(в нем как-то не понятно Hibernate пристроен, то-есть JPA как-то подключает его без явного внедряет в зависимостях Hibernate, потом Security модуль и другие), Logger(slf4j, etc), JUnit, db-connector, если это не Rest, то template engine(thymleaf, freemarker, mustache, etc), если REST, то React/Vue/Angular. Что еще?

Есть ли пример/план, какой используют для реальных приложений? То-есть перечисление всех, что используют со старта вплоть до публикации в сеть. Например видел видео про Spring + webix, используют ли этот webix? Или это не для серьезных приложений, а так, дома поиграться?
А как строить приложения? Каждый по-своему показывает примеры: у кого-то структура проекта состоит например из: model, repository, service, controller, config. У кого-то есть еще пакеты как: dao, dto, handlers и тд и тп. Как понять, какой из них подходящий? У одних есть пакет webapp, в других пакет resources/templates.

Есть ли какая-то статья насчет всего этого, и что нужно считать, как просто обучающий проект, в котором не стоит обращать внимание на такие вещи. А где примеры с правильным построением и использованием лучших технологий, фреймворков для работы. Есть еще такие штуки как Guava и другие, часто ли они используются?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1g3kT0ZcSXt4_ZyJOshKJQ на этом канале подчерпнул для себя много нового.

Comment: посмотрите описание вакансий на java backend